MMS Receiver - get the "text" part of an MMS message and who sent the message
I need to be able to write an MMS Receiver for android and the actual data that is required from the MMS message is the "text" part and who was the sender (phone number of sender)
Now, I wrote the basic, meaning when MMS is sent to my phone I get a call to the newly created receiver (My app is the "default" SMS APP)
But it is not clear to me how to extract the Text part from the message. I saw few examples that iterate over messages , but the type of message I get is always "jpeg" and not the "text" part

In the action received in the MMS Receiver, is there any relevant information that can be extracted?

How to know who sent the MMS message?


Thanks
